# qtsql-querymodel-editablesqlmodel: why need refresh?

Tags: sql, qml

I study for example http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtsql-querymodel-editablesqlmodel-cpp.html
I have one question, why after query UPDATE statement, model is cleared on view (view is empty) and shows data after refresh calling SELECT statement?
I think so, there's no SELECT running and model doesn't have to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model is directly displaying the result of a `SELECT` query, so it displayed the state of the database at the time of querying.

The code that updates the database uses operations that do not directly affect the model's internal data (the cached result of the previous `SELECT` query), so there is no change as far as the view is concerned.

Applying the `SELECT` query again in `refresh()` updates the model's knowledge about that database state and thus results in new data being available in the view.

The "clearing" is caused by the call to `clear()` in `setData()`.
Not sure why it is there, I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: Clear is needed to show changed data, I think. But I have new question concerned of it. If changed item is last of big table and viewed as scrolled down, after refresh listview loses scrolled position and user needs to show its changed value but listview shows first records.

Comment: Listview.scrolltoitem need to use, I think.

Comment: Yes, either manually scroll or, alternatively, implement your own model that updates rather than resets.

Comment: Scrolltoitem doesn't exist as method from Listview.

Comment: Yes, but `positionViewAtIndex()` does